# How to define the size between \scriptsize and \footnotesize?

Tags: fonts, fontsize

I want to change the size of one paragraph in my paper, however, scriptsize is too small for me while footnotesize is very big.

Comment: What about `\fontsize{9}{10}\selectfont`? (I'm guessing larger-than-`10pt` for the default....)

Comment: Rather difficult to say since we have no idea what size `\scriptsize` or `\footnotesize` are without an MWE.

Comment: However, note that your aim is a terrible one. Unless you are writing a paper about the horrors of bad typography and are bizarrely short of sufficient examples.

Comment: What's the basic font size in use in your document? If it's `10pt` and if you're using one of the standard LaTeX classes, `\footnotesize` represents a 20% linear reduction in size (`8pt`), while `\scriptzize` represents a 30% linear reduction in size (`7pt`). Do you want to obtain a 25% linear reduction in font size? Please advise. Incidentally, your claim that `footnotesize` is "very big" is not easy to follow.